# Ho to replace default error page in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django app and in the main `urls.py` I have the

```
handler500 = 'common.view_utils.custom_500'
```

which is supposed to display my custom error page. The code of the `custom_500` is as follows

```
def custom_500(request):
    logger.error(sys.exc_info())
    t = loader.get_template('500.html')
    type, value, tb = sys.exc_info()
    return HttpResponseServerError(t.render(request, {
        'exception_value': value,
        'value': type,
        'traceback': traceback.format_exception(type, value, tb)
    }))
```

However when I tried to test it and raised an `Error` from the view class then Django displayed the default *A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.* error page.

I thought if an `Error` is raised in the code then that is supposed to be a 500 error which will be handled but mu custom error handler but obviously I am mistaken.

Could you please help me what I am missing here?

Thanks,
V.

++++++ UPDATE1 +++++++
Sorry I forgot to mention that the I tried with `DEBUG = False`

Comment: This `custom_500` is supposed to be a view! It should return a `HttpResponse` object. It is not supposed to raise or return(!?) an error.

Comment: Hi, as per Django doc the `HttpResponseServerError` is a `HttpResponse` but with 500 status.  Also I am pretty sure a handler method can be defined in apostrophe which will retrieve the `HttpResponse`. I raised the error in my normal view to test this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You havve to add into your main urls.py every single views wich will be called at the show of the error:

```
handler404 = 'APP_NAME.views.custom_page_not_found_view'
handler500 = 'APP_NAME.views.custom_error_view'
handler403 = 'APP_NAME.views.custom_permission_denied_view'
handler400 = 'APP_NAME.views.custom_bad_request_view'
```

furthermore, you can render a page but you have to set the correct status of the rendering, like:

```
return render(request,'YOUR-PAGE.html',status=404)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Sorry, I am not sure what you mean. In my main `urls.py` I added the `handler500 = 'common.view_utils.custom_500'`. I just want a custom page for the 500 error.

Comment: so you just have to add the handler500, try to change the last line of your code, with the return render i wrote here, you don't need to HttpResponseServerError but simply render as I wrote